# Count number of values of one column group by value of another column

Tags: linux, bash, count

I have a text file like this :

```
asn|prefix|ip|domain
25008|85.192.184.0/21|85.192.184.59|solusi-it.com
25008|85.192.184.0/21|85.192.184.59|samtimes.ru
131755|103.31.224.0/24|103.31.224.58|karosel-ind.com
131755|103.31.224.0/24|103.31.224.58|solusi-it.com
9318|1.232.0.0/13|1.234.91.168|solusi-it.com
9318|1.232.0.0/13|1.234.91.168|es350.co.kr
```

Is there a way that I can count number of unique ips on a unique domain with Linux Bash command and get a result like this?

```
domain|count_ip
solusi-it.com|3
samtimes.ru|1
karosel-ind.com|1
es350.co.kr|1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -F'\|' -lane '                                                            
    $. > 1 and $domains->{$F[3]}->{$F[2]}++;
    END{
        print "domain|count_ip";
        print $_, "|", scalar keys %{ $domains->{$_} } for keys %$domains;
    }
' file | tee new_file
```

The idea behind this is to use a HASH of HASH

```
$domains->{$F[3]}->{$F[2]}++
```

the `$F[3]` is the domain and `$F[2]` is the IP. Uniqueness is guarantee. A HASH key is always unique.

#### OUTPUT:

```
domain|count_ip
es350.co.kr|1
karosel-ind.com|1
samtimes.ru|1
solusi-it.com|3
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. If I want to write the output to a file, I have to add >>output at the end?

Comment: POST updated, I was counting the prefix, not the ip (but same output)

Comment: Thanks. This write the results in a file and print them on the screen also. How can I remove the printing on the screen part?

Comment: `file > new_file` : a basic shell redirection.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
~$ awk -F'|' 'NR>1{a[$NF]++}END{print "domain|count_ip";for (i in a){print i FS a[i]}}' f
domain|count_ip
karosel-ind.com|1
solusi-it.com|3
samtimes.ru|1
es350.co.kr|1
```

You can use [Field separator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html) to have fields separated with `|`.
This won't check if the ip is already in the array `a` though.

In order to do that, you could use `sort` to test uniqueness of 3rd and 4th field:

```
~$ cat f f >f2
~$ sort -t'|' -k3,4 -u f2 | awk -F'|' 'NR>1{a[$NF]++}END{print "domain|count_ip";for (i in a){print i FS a[i]}}'
domain|count_ip
solusi-it.com|3
samtimes.ru|1
es350.co.kr|1
domain|1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
 cat data | tail -n+2 | awk -F'|' '{print  $4" "$3}' | sort | uniq | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2"|"$1}'
```

It basically removes the header, then prints IP and host, finds the unique pairs {ip, host}, counts them with grouping by host and formats them.

edit: corrected formatting